# success function equivalent for httppost in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

What is the equivalent for `success function` when I am using `[HttpPost]` in MVC instead of ajax calls

in ajax, for calling controller in MVC I use something like

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SomeConroller", "ActionName")',
                dataType: 'html', //be sure to use html dataType
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success:someFunctionName

            });
```

I stopped using ajax calls and started using ajax and started using  `[HttpPost]` so that all `input type="submit"` will come to that and i will handle the events to be done.

Now there is a scenario where I am selecting and moving an item to a different list, and after its done i am doing a `this.RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");`

The problem is, once it is done how can i alert that it is moved? if it is `ajax` i will handle it in success function. Where can i handle that here?

Comment: Had to read multiple times before I could make out "I must say please rephrase your question". Its not clear.

Comment: Thanks, I can now understand however for others please rephrase "I stopped using ajax calls and started using ajax and started using  [HttpPost]".

Comment: Store the message in `TempData`, then read it in the GET method you redirect to and display it on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are redirecting to another action, the page will refresh. If you want to display an alert on new page, the action view can display it with the data you pass to the view.

So something like this should give action data that it pass to the view:

```
return RedirectToAction("TargetAction", "Controller", new {id = userId});
```

The "TargetAction" will prepare a view model object and return a view with the view model:

```
        return View(viewModel);
```

View will have logic to display a alert with custom text. E.g. if you want to display javascript alert on load, just define

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Item moved: " + '@Model.Id');
});
```